# UIAlertView throwing exception NSInternalInconsistencyException of UIAlertButton

Tags: objective-c, exception, uialertview

I have been trying hard to figure out why the error is happening with such simple code:

```
UIAlertView *alertDialog;
alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
               initWithTitle:@"Alert button detected"
               message:@"I need your attention NOW"
               delegate:self
               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
               otherButtonTitles:@"Maybe later", @"Never", nil
               ];
[alertDialog show];
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requesting the window of a view (<UIAlertButton: 0x885f020; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)>) with a nil layer. This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:.'

What I have tried:

- deploy in both ios 5 and 6 simulator with errors
- if the buttons are set to **nil**, it works (no buttons shown)

Comment: Your code executes properly in my application. Something you are doing wrong in your class, check if your current class is still in memory

Comment: Your code is working without any error......

Answer (score 0):

I am checking the whole project for settings, additional files and delete one by one until I saw one category class that I have created manually earlier:

```
@interface UIButton (UIButton)
```

which has only **init** method. After deleting this class it works! (or deleting the init method in .m which might be incomplete), though I didn't import it as header into the viewcontroller I am using UIAlertView.

```
-(id)init
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return self;
}
```

Thanks for helps. I will need to look into more appropriate way to implement custom UIButton.